# JS local variable assignment error (Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In Rails 6, I am learning the new webpacker scheme and it's giving me a small headache. Here's my code (truncated to show the error)

```
# in app/javascript/packs/country_cities.js
import Rails from '@rails/ujs';
console.log("Countries!");
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  console.log("L");
  country_select = 1;
});
```

and

```
# in app/javascript/packs/application.js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("channels")
require("packs/country_cities")
```

When I refresh the page I get this error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: country_select` on the line that is assigning 1 to that variable. Why?

Comment: Where are you define the variable `country_select` ? (with `var` or `let`)

Comment: My js is not super. In the past I thought I could get away without a declaraiton?

Comment: If you don't use `var` or `let` your variable is defined into the window object. Not shure but maybe rails make some protection on window object and you can't initialize a variable like that. If you try `var country_select = 1;` it's working ?

Comment: YES! Thanks; but still confused about why!

Comment: If you are using `country_select` just into this scope you can keep this fix. Otherwise it will be necessary to define `country_select` in the upper scope